# JavaScript separate string then decipher number of characters

Tags: javascript, string

So what I am doing is taking a string and splitting it at all the spaces. I already did this using `.split(" ")[0/1/2]` but how do I then take those individual strings and determine the length? The reason I am doing this is to check that string if it has a middle initial or not. Given a name like this John M Smith, I can determine what the words are but if somebody does not enter a middle initial, the last name will now be placed in the middle initial variable. How would I go about doing this or am I tackling it all wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `length` of the array that holds the separated strings:

```
var separateStrings = stringVar.split(' ');
var numOfNames = separateStrings.length;
```

For example, with the following code:

```
var i = document.getElementById('names'); // assuming an input element of id="names"

i.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        var stringVar = this.value,
            separatedNames = stringVar.split(' '),
            numOfNames = separatedNames.length;

        alert(numOfNames);
    }

};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eLUCV/).

Comment: Well, yes. Both answers suggest much the same thing; it's merely the demonstrations that are different. =)

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the result array to see if there is a middle name:

```
var result = "John Smith".split(" ");
if(result.length == 2) {
  //No middle name
  //result[0] == "John"
  //result[1] == "Smith"
}
else if(result.length == 3) {
  //Has middle name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
var parts = "John M Smith".split(" ");
var first = parts[0],
    middle = (parts[2] && parts[1]) || "",
    surname = parts[2] || parts[1];
```

You'll get the correct values for each variable when there's a middle initial and when there is not. Note that this assumes there is always a first and last name, but that the middle initial is optional.

Comment: I am checking that further up to make sure there is at least 2 words separated. Thanks